# Create stacked bar plot with certain columns as 'fill' argument and row summaries as the 'x' argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the datframe below:

```
Target_Category<-c("Adhesion","Cytochrome")
Validated<-c(5,10)
Candidate<-c(7,8)
dataf<-data.frame(Target_Category,Validated,Candidate)
```

and I want to create a stacked bar plot like the one in the image attached in which the `fill` argument should be given by the `Validated` and `Candidate` while the x argument should be the summary of each row.

I have tried something like:

```
p4 <- ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y = , x = Target_Category, fill = ), data = dataf,
                          stat="identity")
p4
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reshape your dataset before plotting:

```
library(tidyverse)

Target_Category<-c("Adhesion","Cytochrome")
Validated<-c(5,10)
Candidate<-c(7,8)
dataf<-data.frame(Target_Category,Validated,Candidate)

dataf %>%
  gather(col, value, -Target_Category) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(Target_Category, value, fill = col), stat="identity")
```

[image]

The rest is about selecting useful names for your variables (i.e what to show on the plot), picking the colours you like and place the legend wherever you want.